# UISearchBar not showing keyboard when tapped

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I programmatically added a UISearchBar in the view, did some initial setup. However, when I tap the search bar, the keyboard is not showing up. I looked up some question on this site, and none seems working for me.

Here is the code snippets I used to setup the search bar

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin.x,origin.y,width,height)];
self.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
self.searchBar.translucent = YES;
self.searchBar.barTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
...
[self.searchBar setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubView:self.searchBar];
```

Any suggestions on fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Xcode 6.0.1?

Comment: @Aaron Yes, I'm using Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: Are you also running in the simulator with a hardware keyboard attached?

Comment: @Aaron I don't have hardware keyboard attached. I can type the search term using my laptop's keyboard, that's all, but the soft keyboard is not showing. I haven't tested this on iPhone yet. So you think this is a simulator problem?

Comment: Possibly. Check my answer. A hardware keyboard may be interfering.

Comment: Do you see the cursor after the searchBar is tapped? If not, maybe it's laid under other views.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're using Xcode 6.0.1, its possible that your hardware keyboard is taking over for the simulator keyboard. When running the simulator, make sure this option is unchecked. This should trigger the simulator keyboard when you tap in your Search Bar:

[image]]

Also, this post explains how to get back to the behavior of the keyboard in Xcode 5.1.1:

[In Xcode 6, how do I use the hardware keyboard but display the software keyboard in the iOS simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25930476/in-xcode-6-how-do-i-use-the-hardware-keyboard-but-display-the-software-keyboard)

Comment: Just adding a comment that this fixed my issue - which was that the screen was just completely going black on the simulator when I clicked into the search bar, but device was working perfectly - although this behaviour just started on the simulator - yesterday the simulator was working fine - so I am not sure how that setting got changed overnight.