# typeText() is typing inconsistent characters

Tags: swift, xctest, xctestcase

I'm beginning to dip my toes into Swift alongside writing UI tests and am having a problem with typing text into a textField. Below is the code:

```
func testLoginUsernameField() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()

    let username = "testusername2"

    let usernameField = app.textFields["username_field"]
    XCTAssertTrue(usernameField.exists)

    usernameField.tap()
    usernameField.typeText(username)
    XCTAssertEqual(usernameField.value as! String, username)
}
```

The problem occurs when I do `usernameField.typeText(username)`. My text continues to write `tstusername2` rather than the `testusername2`.

Comment: How is SwiftUI an appropriate tag here? I see no SwiftUI in the question.

Comment: Try deleting the `tap()`.

Comment: Sorry about that. I deleted the SwiftUI tag. As for deleting tap(), this results in a `Neither element nor any descendant has keyboard focus` error.

Comment: OK darn, that didn't work. Okay, how about this; put back the `tap()` (obviously) and insert a 5-second pause before the `typeText` (I'm assuming you know how to do that). Does that help?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work either. It's odd, it's still typing but it consistently misses the second character, regardless of the word, word length, sleep, etc.

Comment: Truly weird. Of course I can't reproduce the problem so I'm at a loss, sorry.

Comment: Fair enough, I appreciate you trying to help.

Comment: How about if you write `for c in username {usernameField.typeText(String(c))}` ?

Comment: That works! Definitely slows the test a bit, but it works as I'd hoped. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, so what we've learned is it's missing a beat. I think this has something to do with the virtual keyboard. In my test, when I slowed it down, I saw the virtual keyboard rise up after the first letter had been typed. Try disabling the virtual keyboard and run the original test and see if that fixes it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue happens on the simulator when the Hardware Keyboard is enabled.

### Disable the hardware keyboard via the menu

Go to I/O -> Keyboard -> Uncheck "Connect Hardware Keyboard" or use the shortcut ⇧⌘K.

[image]

### Disable the hardware programmatically

If you'd like to disable the hardware keyboard for your Scheme, no matter what simulator you run, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57268609/2109184) StackOverflow post. I attempted to use other methods to disable the hardware keyboard via the App Delegate but had no luck.