# How to disable iOS Simulators Hardware Keyboard (Xcode 13) on fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, simulator, fastlane

I've been trying to get my UI Tests running on our CI/CD server with fastlane, and my lane is set up just fine.

Currently my UI Tests are failing on CI but passing locally, and they are failing because they are not finding the "Delete" key on the software keyboard, leading me to believe that the CI server believes a hardware keyboard is connected, as that is the default state for Simulators.

I was following the guidance from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845373/disable-ios-simulator-connect-hardware-keyboard-programmatically) which seems to no longer work above Xcode 10, and/or doesn't work for fastlane.

It appears that fastlane merged in a fix to natively disable the hardware keyboards on the `snapshot` tool, but that isn't available in with `scan`.

I've tried to implement the script they used for `snapshot` manually in my pre-action build scripts, but I have been unsuccessful.

Has anyone been able to disable the hardware keyboard for iOS simulators with fastlane?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61339150/667586